# how to replace 2 double quotes into single in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace two double quotes into single. Can you please help me?

Example:

```
""My name is shivam.""
```

Expected output:

```
"My name is shivam."
```

I think the problem is coming while saving this dataframe into csv file. dataframe wise it is correct.

Comment: Just to be clear, if I were to put that string into a variable it would be: `'""My name is shivam.""'` and you want that to become  `'"My name is shivam."'`?

Comment: Please, provide more context about the problem. Where does that string appear? A file?

Comment: yes it is one column value. this thing is coming most of the columns.

Comment: df.replace({'\""': '"'}, regex=True)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the replace method.

```
string = '""My name is shivam.""'
string = string.replace('""','"')
print(string)
```

If its in a column, try

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace('""','"')
```

Answer (score 0):

For all columns, just run:

```
df = df.apply(lambda s:s.replace('(")(")','"', regex=True))
```

Comment: Nice Solution, just a heads up, inplace is going to get depreciated. [link](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#:~:text=The%20pandas%20core%20team%20discourages,to%20what%20the%20name%20implies.)

Comment: Please, check it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try

```
df[column_name].replace('""','"',regex=True)
```

[image]

For multiple columns

```
df.replace('""','"',regex=True)
```

[image]

Comment: It is coming in most of the columns.

Comment: Not in single column'.

Comment: then directly use   df.replace()

Comment: But while saving into file it is again coming in 2 double quotes.

Comment: Are you updating the data frame object with the newly generated one like below ? or not?

df = df.replace('""','"',regex=True)


or


df.replace( '""','"',regex=True, inplace = True)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try replace the capture group with its first instance.

```
print(s)

0     ""My name is shivam.""  
1                       Shivan
2                     "Shivan"

s1 = s.replace('(")(")',r'\1',regex=True)

print(s1)

0     "My name is shivam."  
1                     Shivan
2                   "Shivan"
```